# How do i accept multiple clients on this program?

Tags: sockets, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, asyncsocket

Through a lot of learning and research, i wrote a server side program. But the problem with this program is that it doesn't accept multiple clients, and i also wanted to know how to send the output back to client side instead of displaying it on the server side. Can someone please help me out with the code? This is what I've tried till now -

class Program
    {

```
    private static Regex _regex = new Regex("not|http|console|application", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {

            TcpListener serversocket = new TcpListener(8888);
            TcpClient clientsocket = default(TcpClient);
            serversocket.Start();

            Console.WriteLine(">> Server Started");
            clientsocket = serversocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Accept Connection From Client");

            try
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(clientsocket.GetStream()))
                {
                    string line;
                    int lineNumber = 0;
                    while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
                    {
                        lineNumber += 1;
                        foreach (Match match in _regex.Matches(line))
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("Line {0} matches {1}", lineNumber, match.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            clientsocket.Close();
            serversocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You need to spawn a thread for a client(s).

Comment: @leppie could u please help me with the code? I'm still a novice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change it to something like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   TcpListener serversocket = new TcpListener(8888);
   TcpClient clientsocket = default(TcpClient);
   serversocket.Start();

   Console.WriteLine(">> Server Started");
   while(true)
   {
      clientsocket = serversocket.AcceptTcpClient();
      Console.WriteLine("Accept Connection From Client");
      LineMatcher lm = new LineMatcher(clientsocket);
      Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(lm.Run));
      thread.Start();
      Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
   }

   serversocket.Stop();
   Console.WriteLine(" >> exit");
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And then have this seperate class handling the linematching

```
public class LineMatcher{
    private static Regex _regex = new Regex("not|http|console|application", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

    private TcpClient _client;

    public LineMatcher(TcpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(_client.GetStream()))
            {
                string line;
                int lineNumber = 0;
                while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
                {
                    lineNumber += 1;
                    foreach (Match match in _regex.Matches(line))
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Line {0} matches {1}", lineNumber, match.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Closing client");
        _client.Close();
    }
}
```

This is purely a proof of concept and is no way stable code ;)
Please note that this doesn't manage the child-threads in any way.
There is also no correct way of shutting down the listener because of the while(true)

Comment: Thanks alot for the help.. :) how do i improvise it then? :)

Comment: If i want to check for strings from a file, its not happening.. Why is that? It immediately gets disconnected.. Instead of giving the words in the program itself, i want to enable the clients to search for it.. How could i do that? Colud u help me out on that please?